# Deleting entries - Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to firebase and I'm a little lost. I want to delete several entries at once but I don't know how to do it from firebase. I want to delete all the entries that have "status: "requested". Can someone tell me step by step what should I do?

[image]

Comment: Which SDK are you using? JavaScript? Android? iOS?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I use Android

Answer (score 1):

When you don't know the key of the items that you have to remove, you will have to first query the database to determine those keys: Then use the below code..

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query resultNodesToRemove = ref.child("yourDatabaseRef").orderByChild("status").equalTo("requested");

resultNodesToRemove.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot childSnapShot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        childSnapShot.getRef().removeValue();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
});
```

resultNodesToRemove contains the nodes that are to be removed as per your criteria of status being equal to "requested"

Comment: Thanks!!! Sorry for my little knowledge. I want to delete these entries from Firebase. First I want to check that the data is correct and then delete it. I do not want to delete it from the application. Where should I put that code?

Comment: This code will delete the nodes from firebase realtime database and not your application. And the query "resultNodesToRemove" checks if the status is as you said "requested". Let me know if you clearly understand.? You should put this code wherever you want to delete the values from the DB. Lets say you have a button to update DB and onClick of that button u call a method that contains the above code.